Need a formula to subtract times
I do 2 contract jobs per day. I have to subtract 1 hr total each day for commute time. In most cases, this is deducted from my first job commute, and my second job commute is zero. I have formulas for them.
My problem is when I commute for 25 minutes for the first job - this is subtracted from the first job. But my next job might take 50 minutes and I need to deduct the balance of the allowed commute time. I need a conditional formula that figures how much of the 2nd amount to subtract out just 35 minutes from the 2nd job.
Part of my issue is that I can't see to just use numbers because excel and Google sheets have a crazy way they do time duration. First job goes on one row and the second goes on the next row.
Tried to add my two fields:
=if(b2>=1,0,if(b2<1),if((b2+c2)<=1,c2),(40-b2)
I've also tried 1:00 in place of the 1

please share a sample sheet with example of your data and desired result. You can Make an anonymous sample document

Are you trying to allocate the hour proportionally based on the length of each job? Or simply have a formula that recognizes what portion of the hour (if any) is remaining after subtracting the first commute,  then subtract that remainder from the second job?

Excel's native time handling is appalling from a user perspective, but the two key things you need to know are these:

Dates and times in Excel are stored internally as numbers. Excel has no 'date', 'time' or 'date-time' type. Display of dates and times is performed purely by formatting of the underlying numbers.

From a time-span perspective, the number 1 in Excel represents one day - not one hour.


So the value 1 in a formula is equivalent "one day". If you enter 1:00 in a cell, Excel will assume you mean "one hour" and convert it to 1/24 (approx 0.04167).
You can, of course, treat Excel integers as hours or minutes for your own purpose, but you can't mix and match. In your formula you have B2>=1 (presumably meaning "B2 at least one hour") but also 40-B2 (I'm not sure what this means, but it looks like the 40 means "40 minutes"?).
Assuming the values in B2 and C2 represent your first and second commutes in hours, the following formula should work (returning the amount of your second commute to deduct):
=IF(B2 >= 1, 0, IF(B2 + C2 <= 1, C2, 1 - B2))

But if you do this, you cannot enter "half an hour" as 0:30 because Excel will convert this to the relevant fraction of a day (i.e. 1/48). You will need to enter 0.5 directly.
You might prefer to use integer minutes in B2 and C2 instead, in which case simply replace the formula above with:
=IF(B2 >= 60, 0, IF(B2 + C2 <= 60, C2, 60 - B2))

